# I am working on a phishing scanner in java

Tags: java

[image: This is how the program should be]

But I cannot quite seem to figure out what the problem is. The assignment wants me to create a phishing scanner that will assign a point value to each based on my estimate of its likeliness to be in a phishing message. Write an application that scans a file or text for the terms and phrases. For each occurence of a keyword or phrase within the text file, add the assigned point value for the total points for that word or phrase. For each keyword or phrase found, output one line with the word or phrase, the number of occurences and the point total. Then show the point total for the entire message.

This is what I have so far

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhishingScanner {

// list of phishing words
private static final String[] phishingWords = { "DHL", "official",
        "bank", "security", "urgent", "alert", "important", "delivery",
        "ebay", "taxes", "credit", "verify", "confirm", "account",
        "bill", "immediately", "address", "telephone", "ssn", "charity",
        "check", "personal", "confidential", "atm", "warning",
        "fraud", "won", "irs", "owe", "pay" };

// parallel array of point values
private static final int phishingPoints[] = { 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 };

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fileName = args[0].toString();
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    int size = phishingWords.length;
    int wordsCount[] = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        wordsCount[i] = 0;

    while (file.hasNext()) {
        String word = file.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(phishingWords[i]))
                wordsCount[i]++;
    }

    System.out.println("\nWord\t\t\tCount\tPoints\n");
    int totalPoints = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (wordsCount[i] > 0) {
            System.out.printf("%-15s %8d %8d\n", phishingWords[i],
                    wordsCount[i], phishingPoints[i]);               
            totalPoints += phishingPoints[i] * wordsCount[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nTotal points: " + totalPoints);
    file.close();
}

}
```

When I run it this is what I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at PhishingScanner.main(PhishingScanner.java:19)
```

which is this line

```
        String fileName = args[0].toString();
```

Comment: You need to pass a filename as argument to your main when running the program.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @ZouZou

Comment: What do you think `String fileName = args[0].toString();` does? (also note that calling `toString` on a `String` is useless)

Comment: If you don't pass in arguments, then args[0] doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent an unchecked exception like an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException from being thrown in your code try adding some exception handling. In the code below all the logic of the program is surrounded by a try block. If a runtime exception is thrown the program will output some information to the user on how to execute the program and then exit. The program also does seem to catch the specific words to watch out for with phishing scams when passing an actual file as an argument to the program! :0

Some people may say that you should not try to catch runtime exceptions like ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions, and they are probably right, but in this case since it is not simply ignored I think it is appropriate. :D

Thanks for sharing this code. This is actually a pretty useful program.

UPDATED ANSWER:

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class PhishingScanner {

 // list of phishing words
 private static final String[] phishingWords = { "DHL", "official",
    "bank", "security", "urgent", "alert", "important", "delivery",
    "ebay", "taxes", "credit", "verify", "confirm", "account",
    "bill", "immediately", "address", "telephone", "ssn", "charity",
    "check", "personal", "confidential", "atm", "warning",
    "fraud", "won", "irs", "owe", "pay" };

  // parallel array of point values
 private static final int phishingPoints[] = { 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3,
    3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 };

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

try { 
    String fileName = args[0].toString();
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    int size = phishingWords.length;
    int wordsCount[] = new int[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    wordsCount[i] = 0;

while (file.hasNext()) {
    String word = file.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(phishingWords[i]))
            wordsCount[i]++;
}

System.out.println("\nWord\t\t\tCount\tPoints\n");
int totalPoints = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (wordsCount[i] > 0) {
        System.out.printf("%-15s %8d %8d\n", phishingWords[i],
                wordsCount[i], phishingPoints[i]);               
        totalPoints += phishingPoints[i] * wordsCount[i];
    }
}
System.out.println("\nTotal points: " + totalPoints);
file.close();


} catch(Exception e) { 
     System.out.println("Please enter a file when running the program"); 
  System.out.println("Example: java PhishingScanner EmailFromMom.txt");

}
}//end method main

 }
```

Comment: I created a text file called phishwords.txt that has the 30 words and phrases. But I did not put it into my code bc I didnt know where to put it. Could that be the reason why?

Comment: @user3255176 Oh, wow. I just ran the program on my system and found some errors. I fixed the code. Please, check it out the updates above. This works on my file system. Thanks for sharing this source code. This is a cool program man. Let me know how it works for you. :D

Comment: Maybe I should have explained a little more what the program should do. When I run it I get "Please enter a file when running the program...." I will post the pic for you

Comment: @user3255176 You need to pass a file to the program to work like you want. :D To do this create some sort of text file, in your favourite text editor, with some test words in it and put it in the same directory as the program. Name this test file test.txt then run the program like so: `java PhishingScanner test.txt`